# Create a ZIP file from a text file using PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have a text file that contains the path to multiple files in the server, 1 file per line, is there a way to read those lines and create a zip from em?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the file, read the other files, put them into a zip. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has functions for creating zips.

Here is a simple example: http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

You'll need to read the file names, put them into a list, and use the function in the example.

Comment: i checked the code and looks that is what i'm looking for, but the text file i mentioned has 500+ lines, so i need to copy/paste those lines and add em like the Sample usage? can php do it automatically with a script or function?

Comment: Read the file line by line, add each line to an array, and pass the array in as the files parameter.